# Add tooltip with timestamp to post notice about lock

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tooltips, post-notices, locked

Most dates/ages/etc. on Stack Exchange have a nice feature; if you hover over them, you see the exact UTC timestamp they represent. Can this feature be added to the lock duration in the post notice?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lock notices now have timestamps that will show when hovering on the `$timeLeft$` text, which will show the exact expiration time (UTC).